# jquery return false killed submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use loop to validate each of every `input` whether they are filled or not. But end up my submit_form function doesn't get triggered.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
var hold = true;
if ($('.tab2').hasClass('active') && hold == true) {

  $('.tab-content:visible input').each(function(i, val) {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      alert("Please fill in valid " + $(this).attr('data-error'));
      $(this).focus();
      hold = true;
      return false;
    } else {
      hold = false;
    }
  });

  return false; //can't remove this
}

submit_form(); //not triggered although all inputs are filled

})
```

if I removed the `return false`, there will be no checking..

Comment: outside if condition you can put return true...so if condition true then return false else it will go for return true

Comment: @Tanmay it doesn't work, have u tried?

Comment: make a fiddle so that i can try else i have to make everything from input fields to js

Comment: `var hold = true;` and in next line you are checking for `hold == true`, it will never be false. If you want to use flag, define it outside click handler. Or maybe, use instead of last `return false;`, `return hold;`

Comment: @Tanmay https://jsfiddle.net/z5j61fkz/

Comment: @A.Wolff can you show me here? https://jsfiddle.net/z5j61fkz/